# Promise function not returning result

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, promise

I have a Card class where I am calling an `all()` function. I am doing a promise call inside it but I never get the result back. Any idea why?

```
class Card {
  static all() {
    this.getUsers().then((result) => {
      console.log('result') // doesn't print
      return result
    })
  }
  get getUsers() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      console.log('test')// doesn't print
      chrome.storage.local.get({ user: [] }, function (result) {
        chrome.storage.local.set({ user: [] }, () => { });
        resolve(result.user);
      });
    });
  }
}

let profile = new CardProfile(element).all()
```

Comment: `all` shouldn’t be `static`!? `all` needs to `return this.getUsers()`.

Comment: If you want to call `this.getUsers()`, then `getUsers` should not be a getter property but a normal method - drop the `get` keyword.

Comment: The code you posted does throw multiple exceptions before the promise even comes into play.